# Upload file using own web service api

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I try to upload file via post and ajax, but I just got the URL to be change.

I don't want change URL like this
http://localhost:8080/webportal.html?file=C%3A%5CUsers%5CVM9%5CDesktop%5Ctest5.txt

I want file be uploaded

This is my code ...

```
HTML

<form id="uploadForm">
    <label>Upload File:</label><br/>
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

---

```
JavaScript
function UploadTestCase()
{
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var requireData = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ip/webapi/upload?project=test", 
                type: "POST",
                data: requireData,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false
           })
           return false;
        }));
    });
}
```

---

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: use return false after the $.ajax({...});return false;
And if there is only file input then set the ajax parameter 'processData' , and 'contentType' to false

Comment: yeah thanks, but not anything changed... btw, the web service api require 
Header : enctype = multipart/form-data.

Comment: You can't use "this" to access the form inside the ajax code..take a variable after the prevent default code.. as var data = new FormData(this).. And pass that to the ajasx data parameter.

Comment: I edit the post that show what I done. But still not work for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Untitled Document</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('#uploaad_file').on('submit', function(e){
                    var data = new FormData(this);

                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'index.php',
                        data : data,
                        processData:false,
                        contentType: false,
                        type: 'POST',           
                        success: function(){
                            console.log(r);
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            console.log(arguments);
                        }
                    })
                    return false;
                })
            })
            </script>
            </head>

            <body>
            </body>
            <form id="uploaad_file" enctype="">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
            <input type="submit" value="upload">
            </form>
            </html>
```

I ahve used this code. And it successfully posted the form data to my server side. I can view $_FILES array with print_r. And it all looks perfect.